# if $f$ is even then $F$ is odd and unique

Tags: calculus

If $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$ and not the $0$ function:
Prove if $f$ is even then there is only one $F$ s.t $F(x)=\int_{}^{}f$ and $F$ is odd

Comment: Presumably you mean that there is only one way to choose the integration constant so that $F$ is odd. So what is the difficulty? How far have you got?

Comment: I've tried to assume there are 2 and try to get that they are equal. by doing the integration

Comment: $f$ might not even be differentiable. So what can we say about $f$ if it is continuous and even? What does that tell us about the integral?

Comment: $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt...=-F(-x)$ so $F$ is odd hence $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f +C$

Comment: @almagest i think i manged to complete the proof, thank you!

Comment: @vonkuman That is the right idea, but be careful about using $F$ with two different meanings. You might want to look at Kavi Rama Murthy's answer below. In general you will get more upvotes and less downvotes if you put something about your efforts to solve the problem into the question. People don't like the idea that they might just be doing someone's homework for them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $F(x)=\int_0^{x} f(t)dt$ (where $\int_a^{b} f(t) dt$ is interpreted as $-\int_b^{a} f(t) dt$  when $ a>b$) makes $F$ odd. Adding any non-zero  constant to it  distroys this property.

Answer (score 1):

G(x)=-G(-x) => G'(x)=G'(-x)=f(x)

$\int$ G'(x)= G(x) + c =F(x) ,as G(x) is odd , and c[a constant function] is only odd when c is 0(otherwise even).

(odd function) + (even function) $\not =$ odd function

(odd function) + (odd fuction) = (odd function)

hence proved

Comment: What is $G(x)$?